# Tableview cell returns nil when selected in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

This code reads from a json file and returns the "name" value in all cells, this is working fine, but when I select the value it keeps returning nill, I want to get the value. I tried some other solutions in other questions because they are in Objective C and this is swift, I tried though and didn't work at all. All I want is the value inside the cell.
Also I want to pass the value of the "id" as well, which is data["id"] of the selected cell, is that possible.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell //1

    let data = datas[indexPath.row]

    if let captionLabel = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel {
        if let caption = data["name"].string{
            captionLabel.text = caption
        }
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();

    let currentCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;

    println(currentCell.textLabel!.text)
    self.viewofloc.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: Looks like the view with tag 100 is not the same as `textLabel`.

Comment: I would use a tag of 1000 and above since tags below that can be used by apple without you knowing it also in your didSelect method you already have the selected `indexPath` passed into the method hence just use that to get the `UITableViewCell`

Comment: @dasdom text label has tag 100

Comment: @darren102 I changed it to 1000, still not working

Comment: I know. But here `println(currentCell.textLabel!.text)` you are referencing the textLabel of the cell. Not the label with the tag 100.

Comment: @dasdom how do i reference the tag in the print?

Comment: You shouldn't even be trying to access the data from the cell -- cells are for displaying data, not supplying it. You have the indexPath passed in to didSelectRowAtIndexPath, so use that to query your data source.

Comment: @darren102: I was going crazy over this. Tag (0) worked for me regularly, but in a new project with a split view controller a tag of 1001 solved my problem. So simple, yet way overlooked as a solution. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: provides an index path for your selected cell. No need to recalculate it with self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.

Try to edit your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` with this:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let currentCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!;
    }
```

I had tried this with new Xcode project (Master-Detail Application) and got a cell.

Comment: I removed   let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
and I'm still getting nil

Comment: Did you get nil for currentCell variable or other object?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the tags and just create a simple `UITableViewCell` subclass then access the UILabel directly. You'll see expanding your cell will get cumbersome using tags.

Also, your indexPath is already supplied in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` so grab your cell using the supplied `tableView` and `indexPath`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? ImageCell

    let data = datas[indexPath.row]

    if let caption = data["name"] as? String {
        cell.labelCaption.text = caption
    }

    return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ImageCell;

    println(currentCell.textLabel!.text)
    self.viewofloc.hidden = true
}

class ImageCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var labelCaption: UILabel!
}
```

Comment: I'm getting "image cell does not have a member named labelCaption"

Comment: Did you set the class to ImageCell in the identity inspector of your cell in the storyboard and tie in the outlet?

Comment: the identity inspector gives me an illegal configuration error.

Comment: fixed it and still nill